# Controlled form: display a div if invalid input

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

For a training, I'am trying to check if the input value of this code base includes a "@" when `onBlur`:

```
<form>
  <input
    type='text'
    name='my_input'
    value={inputValue}
    onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
    onBlur={(e) => checkEmail(e.target.value)}
    ></input>
  <button>Save</button>
</form>
```

Therefore I added a function to display a `<div>` below the form (or at least below the input field) if there is no "@" in the input, but without success:

```
function checkEmail(value) {
  if (!value.includes('@')) {
    <div>⚠️ Warning, there is no @, this is not a valid email address.</div>;
  }
}
```

Knowing `console.log(!value.includes('@'))` well return true.

Any clue on how to get the `<div>⚠️ Warning, there is no @, this is not a valid email address.</div>` shown below the form or input when invalid input?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use type="email"? Browsers have automatic validation for all kinds of input types.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning your JSX in the `checkEmail` function, which isn't quite right. What you want to do instead is have a flag that indicates whether the warning JSX should be rendered, and setup a logic to do so if it is true. `inputValue` being a state is really handy in this case, one small `&&` operator should handle the rendering function.

```js
<form> ... </form>

{ inputValue && !inputValue.includes('@') && 
(<div>⚠️ Warning, there is no @, this is not a valid email address.</div>) }
```

**PS:**
you can get rid of `onBlur={(e) => checkEmail(e.target.value)}` and its handler method.

Comment: Good tip! Thanks. 
However, the `<div>` alert is by default displayed (when no text filled in), that's why the `onBlur` was pertinent.
And when typing `!value.includes('@') && (<div>⚠️ Warning, there is no @, this is not a valid email address.</div>)` directly in the `checkEmail` function, it is not working...

Comment: I edited the condition to ignore the case when nothing has been entered. You can get rid of the `checkEmail` function entirely.

Comment: Not optimized in term of UX design (it shows up directly when typing), but works fine. Thanks!

Comment: No probs! Would appreciate it if you could mark the answer as accepted. It would only be fair to do so if it works for you.